# Admob Interstitial messes up my CALayers

Tags: admob, calayer

I have a game which runs CALayer perfectly.  However, every time I show Admob Interstitial, the CALayer is messed up completely.

I have tried "[self.view setNeedsDisplay]" to redraw, but the issue is still there.

The workaround is to clear the screen and redo the CALayer properly

However, the user will see, even if it's for a few seconds, the messed up CALayer

How can I resolve this, please?